# Get today's date in Jekyll with Liquid markup

Tags: ruby, datetime, jekyll, liquid

This (should) be easy, I think, but I'm unable to get today's date to show in a Jekyll page using Liquid markup. According to [the documentation](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/wiki/Liquid-for-Designers), I should be able to do this to get this date's year:

```
{{ 'now' | date: "%Y" }}
```

But all that gets rendered is the string `now`, not any formatted date. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I assume this bug is already fixed. using jekyll 3.2.1 and `ruby 2.0.0p481 (2014-05-08 revision 45883) [universal.x86_64-darwin14]` it's working

Comment: Now it works fine.

Answer (score 137, accepted):

It didn't work for me either. It appears you've hit a current bug in the Ruby 1.9.3 support. There is a [pull request](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/pull/117) that fixes the bug, but it's not incorporated yet. A workaround is listed, perhaps it will work for you:

```
{{ site.time | date: '%y' }}
```

Comment: or {{ site.time | date: '%Y' }} for 2014

Comment: Pretty sure this only gets the time from the last time you ran the `jekyll` command. Theoretically, if you don't update your site much, this could get stale.

All in all, it's not the same as getting the current time.

Comment: @menehune23 The point is moot anyway. The fix has been incorporated into jekyll, so the OP's code works and there is no need for this workaround anymore.

Comment: Agreed. Just wanted to point it out for those who don't know that it's in there now (and who haven't tried it for themselves)

Comment: @menehune23 Not sure if you're implying that this workaround is any different than what the OP was trying to do.

Comment: Ah, so it seems both approaches only capture the time at build, not the time of access. Guess that makes sense in thinking about it, because you'd need JavaScript for the latter

Comment: Lowercase `%y` would print two digit year like `22` whereas uppercase `%Y` would print full four digit `2022`

Answer (score 9):

To get the whole year, for example **"2015"**, from the `site.time`, you can either use:

```
{{ site.time | date: '%Y' }}
# OR
20{{ site.time | date: '%y' }}
```

To just get the last 2 digits from the year 2015, this will just output **"15"**:

```
{{ site.time | date: '%y' }}
```

Comment: This basically repeats the comment after my answer.

Comment: @MarkThomas But still have the great explanation.

Comment: @MarkThomas You should update your answer with the post-Ruby 1.9.3 answer.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps the question title is misleading but I actually wanted today's date and not the year. This works for me:

```
{{ site.time | date: '%B %d, %Y' }}
```

Today it produced: January 04, 2019

Answer (score -1):

`{{ site.time }}` represent the time the site did get updated it is a fixed date not a dynamic one.

Such request require Javascript with `Date.getTime()` or `Date.now()` example:

```
<script>document.write(Math.round(Date.now() / (365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) + 1970 - 1));</script>
```

Comment: This is unnecessarily verbose. If you are going to use JS, then use `Date` for an object instead of `Date.now` an integer. `x = newDate(); x.getFullYear(); // 2021`