# liquid transform of string value to date format

Tags: azure, liquid, azure-logic-apps

I have just started using liquid mapping in Logic apps for transforming json data to text. I have to convert date in a specific format.
In the json data, I have date value as `20181230T000000.000 GMT` and i want to transform the date in "MMddyy" format.

I had used `{{"now" | Date: "MMddyy"}}`
for transforming current date to specific format.
But when i am using the same syntax of transforming current date in specific format it works as in following answer 
[Date Math / Manipulation in Liquid Template Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21056965/date-math-manipulation-in-liquid-template-filter?rq=1)

But when the same syntax I am trying to utilize while picking up data from JSON, it's not working. what could be possibly wrong?

Json data example:

```
{
    "ItemSerialNumber" : "ItemSerialNumber",
    "ExchangeOrderNo" : "ExchangeOrderNo",
    "ShipDate" : "20181230T000000.000 GMT"
}
```

transformation syntax tried : `{{content.ShipDate | Date: "MMddyy"}}`

but it didn't worked and output came `20181230T000000.000 GMT`

Comment: did you ever solve this?

Answer (score -1):

You should use the set the date using the format directives (a full list of which can be found [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Time.html#method-i-strftime)

So `{{ "20181230T000000.000 GMT" | date: "%m %d %y" }}` outputs `12 30 18`

And `{{ "20181230T000000.000 GMT" | date: "%B %d %y" }}` outputs `December 30 18`

This should also work using `{{ "content.ShipDate" | date: "%m %d %y" }}` outputs `12 30 18`

Comment: The date filter doesn't work on strings.  https://jumpseller.com/support/liquid-sandbox/